# TypeScript Express Error Function

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-typings

What are the types of the four parameters for the error handling function when coding in Typescript?

```
app.use((err: ??, req: ??, res: ??, next: ??) => { });
```

I am using VS Code and no hints are offered. I get red wiggly lines under all four parameters.

The error says "Parameter implicitly has 'any' type". Actually I am confused with this message. If it treats it as an `any` type, then isn't that a valid choice?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The function itself has the following signature (taken from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/507e9d3c8e48b2db81d3e071d270a2a297eed151/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L32)):

```
export type ErrorRequestHandler = (err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => any;
```

So you can either declare the function as a variable of type `ErrorRequestHandler` or type the parameters according to that definition.

*Note: the typings for "express-serve-static-core" are imported and re-exported by the typings for "express", which was where I looked for the above definition.*

```
import type { ErrorRequestHandler } from "express";
```

```
const errorHandler: ErrorRequestHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {};

app.use(errorHandler);
```

Regarding your second question related to implicit `any`, it is the "implicit" part that is causing the problem, If you explicitly type as `any` then there won't be any error (but there won't be any typings either; consider using [`unknown`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51439876/4554883) instead).

You can also disable `noImplicitAny` in your compiler config but I wouldn't recommend it personally, as it protects you from several classes of bugs.

Comment: Thanks. When I explicitly declare the function as type `ErrorRequestHandler`, it says "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value." What can I return for this function? I tried `return res.render(...` but that is of type void.

Comment: @OldGeezer Sounds like you might have put the typing in the wrong place, possibly in the return type of the function `(...): ErrorRequestHandler => ...`. One way to type the function is to use `const yourHandler: ErrorRequestHandler = (...) => ...` and then `app.use(yourHandler)`.

Answer (score 18):

I don't know why Typescript does not get that we are passing an error handler.

These are the solutions I found possible :

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {}) // KO    

const inVariable : ErrorRequestHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {};

app.use(inVariable); // ok
app.use(((err, req, res, next) => {}) as ErrorRequestHandler); // ok
```

Comment: The approach to explicitly cast the handler to `ErrorRequestHandler` did the trick for me.

Comment: `satisfies` seems to work as well. Might be better than type casting. `app.use(((err, req, res, next) => {}) satisfies ErrorRequestHandler);`

Answer (score 14):

### Custom Error Type

Using `any` completely gives up the type checking advantage of the Typescript. Because in JavaScript, one can `throw` anything, for `err` parameter, the type `unknown` can be used from Typescript 3.0 onwards:

```
app.use((err: unknown, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => { })
```

### Example

Create a custom error, if you need it, like following:

```
// HttpException.ts in exceptions directory of your project.

export class HttpException extends Error {
  public status: number
  public message: string
  constructor(status: number, message: string) {
    super(message)
    this.status = status
    this.message = message
  }
}
```

And then import the custom error wherever you are using it:

```
import { HttpException } from './exceptions/HttpException'

app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const err = new HttpException(404, 'Not Found')
    // Do something with error here...
    next(err)
})

app.use((err: unknown, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    if (err instanceof HttpException) {
        // Do something more with the error here...
    }
    next(err)
})
```

Because the type of `err` is `unknown`, we cannot directly access or modify the `err`. First we need to check the type using `instanceof` which as a result, smart casts the `err` to that type (`HttpException` in our case).

We can add any properties and methods to the `HttpException` class as and when required, like we have added `status` and `message`.

---

### Type Definitions

In case you haven't done already, you need to install type definitions for Node.js and Express.js for your Typescript project. This will make sure the types `Request`, `Response` and `NextFunction` will be recognised and auto-imported.

To install type definitions for Node.js:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

To install type definitions for Express.js:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/express
```

---

That's it! Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `ErrorRequestHandler` as follows:

```
import type { ErrorRequestHandler } from "express";

type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;

type ErrorRequestHandlerArgs = ArgumentTypes<ErrorRequestHandler>;

app.use((...args: ErrorRequestHandlerArgs) => {
  const [err, req, res, next] = args;
  // ...
});
```