# Express.js & TypeScript: How to simplify parameter types for app.use callback for error handling

Tags: typescript, express, types

Having some experience with TypeScript but being new to Express.js, I want to create a generic error handler in my Express.js app written in TypeScript. The following code works in JavaScript:

```javascript
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(new createError[404]());
});

// error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

When trying to compile this with TypeScript however, it does not like the anonymous function in the *second* `app.use` call:

```
error TS7006: Parameter 'err' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
         ~~~

error TS7006: Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
              ~~~

error TS7006: Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
                   ~~~

error TS7006: Parameter 'next' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
                        ~~~~
```

Apparently, TypeScript was able to infer the type information of the parameters in the anonymous function for the *first* `app.use` call. It was not able to infer it for the *second* one though.

When changing the line into the following, TypeScript at least does not spit out any errors anymore... but `eslint` is angry with me because now I'm using implicit `any`s:

```typescript
app.use((err: any, req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
```

Alternatively, Visual Studio Code allows me to apply a quick fix "Infer parameter types from usage" on the second anonymous function. This turns the second `app.use` line into this beauty (line breaks added by me):

```typescript
app.use((err: { message: any; status: any; },
         req: { app: { get: (arg0: string) => string; }; },
         res: { locals: { message: any; error: any; };
                status: (arg0: any) => void;
                render: (arg0: string) => void; },
         next: any) => {
```

While this would do its job, I feel that this beast is pretty much unmaintainable and incomprehensible.

So now I wonder: How would you implement something like this without sacrificing maintainability and comprehensibility?

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/fc1496ba565ee3950dca197305e2da911cb6a0d1/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L68-L79

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thank you for the link to this type definition. Do I get it correctly that this type definition is not included in @types/express and I would have to add it manually to my project? If yes, why is that so?

Comment: That type is in `@types/express-serve-static-core`, which `@types/express` depends on.

Comment: Ah, I see. I (obviously) have `@types/express` installed. So why can't `tsc` automatically infer this type definition from my code?

Comment: I think it *is* doing, which is why it's telling you that err is implicitly (because you haven't provided an explicit type) any (because that's the type of any in the definition I linked).

Comment: I think that there is something else going on. Unfortunately I had only copy/pasted the first of the error messages that TypeScript gave me into the original version of this question. I've just added the other ones as well. As you can see, TypeScript is not only complaining about `err` being `any` but also about the other ones. If I understood your theory correctly, TypeScript should have inferred the types correctly for the other ones and should not have reported errors for them, right?

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly the inference breaks down there, but the fixes are shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65517283/3001761.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `app.use(((err, req, res, next) => {/* code */}) as ErrorRequestHandler);` does the trick. Will vote to close this question in favor of the one you linked now.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is comming from the settings you have in tsconfig.json

```
"noImplicitAny": true
```

It is good practice to have strict typescript. This is how I handle the errors and this are the types for each argument.
Install this package

```
npm i -D @types/express
```

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
...
this.app.use((error: unknown, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void => {
      if (error instanceof HttpException) {
        res.status(error.code).send({ message: error.message });
        return;
      }

      if (error instanceof Error && error.message) {
        if (error.message === 'Method not implemented') {
          res.status(501).send({ message: httpStatusCode(501) });
          return;
        }

        res.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
        return;
      }

      res.status(500).send({ message: httpStatusCode(500) });
      return;
    });
```

And this is the HttpException class if you wonder what is

```
export class HttpException {
  constructor(public code: number, public message: string = httpStatusCode(code)) {}
}
```

With this setup in conjuntion with an async handler for the middleware you can throw errors or even have promises that fails and the errors are handled in one place.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this alternative. I was looking for a solution with more automatic inference. See the comments above on how I finally solved it.