Why TypeScript does not get the Type of error callback in Express
I have this piece of code in Express TypeScript
import { Router } from "express";

export const skillsRouter = Router()

skillsRouter.use((req, res, next) => {}) // Typescript knows the types of req, res and next
skillsRouter.use((err, req, res, next) => {}) // TypeScript throws implicit any error 

skillsRouter.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json("ok")
}) // Typescript again knows the types of req and res

Why doesn't it know the types of the Error handler params
Also I'm aware that this will fix it
skillsRouter.use(((err, req, res, next) => {}) as ErrorRequestHandler)

or this
skillsRouter.use((err: unknown, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {})


I never used error handling in that way on express but this should answer it quite well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218878/typescript-express-error-function

Looked at the link but none of the answers there explain what I'm asking. I'm asking why Typescript doesn't infer the types the function when there are 4 arguments as in an error handler?

i don't know why its like that but if you look at the source code use just has the types for handler not for error handler so have to explicitly type it, not ideal but its as it is, you can overwrite types if you want to.

I've been looking at the source, it's a bit hard to grasp since I'm still learning typescript but I've messed with the source code in my node_modules and after commenting out some portions of it, typescript is able to infer types for the error handler but unable to detect for the other overloads, ie (req, res) and (req, res, next).
